# MAMP 4.0.3 won't start MySQL server (caused by ib_logfile)

Tags: mysql, drupal, mamp, drupal-8

Before I start writing down my problem I want to stress out that I already did some intensive research (both here and elsewhere on the web) on the problem. But to no avail. The cause of my problem lies elsewhere.

**Problem**

I recently installed MAMP 4.0.3 on Mac OS El Capitan (10.11.6) running multiple Drupal 8 websites. All worked fine until I had to put my computer to sleep and after it woke up the MySQL server won't start again.

**What I tried**

1. All the solutions offered on the web (no processes running, etc..)
2. I tried a new install, and that worked but after copying the db files to the new folder the same problem emerged: MySQL server refuses to start. The problems appear when following files are copied to the db directory of MAMP: auto.cnf, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1.
3. I tried with a clean install and copied only the project folder (containing the .ftm and .ibd files) and let MAMP create the auto.cnf, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1 files. But again, not working.
4. Tried (on a new install) to create an empty database (same name) and then copied the files to the db directory: same problem.

**Info**

MAMP 4.0.3

Mac OS X 10.11.6

Console output when MySQL server fails:

```
27/09/16 08:52:30,739 MAMP[8863]: -[MAMPBonjourController startBrowsing]
27/09/16 08:52:30,741 MAMP[8863]: -[MAMPBonjourController publishHostViaBonjour:onPort:]: mamphostAtimac_sven_van_uytfanghe
27/09/16 08:52:31,003 MAMP[8863]: -[MAMPBonjourController(MAMPBonjourControllerPrivate) registerHost:withName:onPort:IP:]: mamphostAtimac.sven.van.uytfanghe.local
27/09/16 08:52:31,003 MAMP[8863]: Registering SERVICE mamphostAtimac_sven_van_uytfanghe._http._tcp
27/09/16 08:52:31,003 MAMP[8863]:  HOST mamphostAtimac.sven.van.uytfanghe.local
27/09/16 08:52:31,003 MAMP[8863]:  PORT 8888
27/09/16 08:52:31,841 MAMP[8863]: -[MAMPBonjourController netServiceDidPublish:] -> _mamp._tcp. (mamphostAtimac_sven_van_uytfanghe)
27/09/16 08:52:31,842 MAMP[8863]: Got a reply for record mamphostAtimac.sven.van.uytfanghe.local: 
27/09/16 08:52:31,842 MAMP[8863]: Name now registered and active
27/09/16 08:52:31,842 MAMP[8863]: Got a reply for service mamphostAtimac_sven_van_uytfanghe._http._tcp.local.: 
27/09/16 08:52:31,842 MAMP[8863]: Name now registered and active
27/09/16 08:52:32,242 MAMP[8863]: -[MAMPBonjourController netServiceBrowser:didFindService:moreComing:]
27/09/16 08:52:32,270 MAMP[8863]: -[MAMPBonjourController netServiceDidResolveAddress:]
```

[MAMP screen - MySQL not launching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tupHn.png)

Note: that thee 'Start Servers' button remains active.

Anywone willing to point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**What I learned**

Make daily backups, SQL dumps :(

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your /Applications/MAMP/logs/ folder, there should be a mysql_error_log.err file with more information on the actual reason why your MAMP / MySQL setup fails to load.

Your InnoDB database might be corrupted.  Using the innodb_force_recovery  setting in your mysqld option file, you might get your mysql up and running to start the recovery: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

These guides might help you recover it: http://blackbird.si/mysql-corrupted-innodb-tables-recovery-step-by-step-guide/